# Show station name on lock screen using iOS Developer

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova and edited the MainViewController to allow the audio to play in the background for the controls to work, but what I would now like to do is show the station Image on the front (like album cover, I guess you could say).

The image would be stored in the app itself (if that is possible) otherwise I guess we can put it on the server and ping that image each time - whatever is easiest.

I am wondering how do I can do this?

My current MainViewController:

```
    /*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  MainViewController.h
//  HelloCordova
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation MainViewController

/*- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}*/

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization

            NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

        } 
        return self; 
    }

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

/* Comment out the block below to over-ride */

/*
- (UIWebView*) newCordovaViewWithFrame:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return[super newCordovaViewWithFrame:bounds];
}
*/

#pragma mark UIWebDelegate implementation

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}

/* Comment out the block below to over-ride */

/*

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    return [super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView];
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    return [super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
*/

- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
    {
        return YES;
    }

- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent*) event
    {
        // see [event subtype] for details
    }

@end

@implementation MainCommandDelegate

/* To override the methods, uncomment the line in the init function(s)
   in MainViewController.m
 */

#pragma mark CDVCommandDelegate implementation

- (id)getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className
{
    return [super getCommandInstance:className];
}

/*
   NOTE: this will only inspect execute calls coming explicitly from native plugins,
   not the commandQueue (from JavaScript). To see execute calls from JavaScript, see
   MainCommandQueue below
*/
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [super execute:command];
}

- (NSString*)pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath;
{
    return [super pathForResource:resourcepath];
}

@end

@implementation MainCommandQueue

/* To override, uncomment the line in the init function(s)
   in MainViewController.m
 */
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [super execute:command];
}

@end
```

Side note, I used Node.js to create this using there Cordova install

Comment: Beware that mis use of controls and functions might get your app reject by Apple. The `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` and playing audio in the background is for music players only.

Comment: But We are playing music, and you can class a radio station app as a music player

Comment: What are you looking for? It seems like you want someone to code something for you? I don't see what the relevance of the code you included is? I removed the `node.js` tag as this question isn't about `node.js`

Comment: @RussellHarrower Sorry, I miss understood. I thought you where creating a (train)station app. You wan't look at either a plugin supporting `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` or build it your self.